# CSS Polaroid style image/caption scaling issues

Tags: html, css

I have fixed proportion images and I would like to wrap them in a polaroid style graphic with a caption using CSS. The total image should take up approximately 60% of the vertical height of the screen and the width should scale accordingly.

Markup

```
<span>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/320/320">
    <div>Kitler, 1978</div>
</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
  border: none;
  height: 60vh;
  position: absolute;
}

span img {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1rem solid white;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

span div {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1rem solid white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Example [here](http://www.cssdesk.com/tP35b)

Unfortunately, when the window is narrowed vertically it distorts the image likewise, and when the window is narrowed horizontally the size of the image falls out of sync with the size of the caption.

What is the cause of this? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the *height* to `img` instead of `span`, and add `width: auto`.

Additionally I put the background in the span and center the image to improve the visualization.

```
span {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  text-align:center;
}

span img {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1rem solid white;
  padding: 0;
  height:55vh;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
}

span div {
  border: 1rem solid white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```